# Reading Data From Firestore using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[Documents Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSb3i.png)

Does Anyone Say What is the Error? Its not getting the Documents Field from Firestore ???

Comment: Please add your code and error details as text in your question, in such a way they can be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Change documents to docs, It will work fine.

Comment: Yeah Bro Just Know Got it i Missed <QuerySnapshot> in Streambuilder